# Curl returns empty string

Tags: php, curl

I have rather strange issue. I have an access to site(email and password). Sorry, but I can not show this site to you. I need to get some info from it's content.
Instead of that I gonna show you my code.

```
//I form string of post request
$fields=array(
    'name_of_login_field' => urlencode('test@gmail.com'),
    'name_of_password_field' => urlencode('pass')
);
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) 
{ 
    $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; 
}
$fields_string=rtrim($fields_string, '&');
```

Then I send it via curl.

```
$curlURL="URL";
if( $curl = curl_init() ) 
{
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $curlURL);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);  
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "mozilla/5.0 (ipad; cpu os 7_0_4 like mac os x) applewebkit/537.51.1 (khtml, like gecko) version/7.0 mobile/11b554a safari/9537.53"); 

    $out = curl_exec($curl);
    var_dump($out);
    //var_dump($out);
    curl_close($curl);
}
```

A site has a form with two inputs (login-password). Also it has a submit button with name and some hidden input with name - redirect.
If I set an google.com, or our site as `$curCURL` I receive a string of its content. If I use URL of site I need to parse, I receive empty string. How it is possible. I ask for suggestions. May be someone met anything similar?

**UPDATE**
Here is my fresh curl:

```
if( $curl = curl_init() ) 
{
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $curlURL);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);  
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "mozilla/5.0 (ipad; cpu os 7_0_4 like mac os x) applewebkit/537.51.1 (khtml, like gecko) version/7.0 mobile/11b554a safari/9537.53"); 

    $out = curl_exec($curl);
    var_dump($out);
    //var_dump($out);
    curl_close($curl);
}
```

With that curl `$out` is `false`. If I remove string with `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` `$out` is empty string.

**UPDATE1**
I checked

```
curl -l desired-site.com
```

it returned only content without headers.
Then I checked

```
curl -s -D - desired-site.com -o /dev/null
```

It returned this headers.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.2.1
Date: Thu, 07 May 2015 08:20:23 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.4-14+deb7u11
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=randon_number_of_letters; expires=Sat, 09-May-2015 12:07:03 GMT; path=/
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: private
Cache-Control: no-store, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Last-Modified: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT
```

Can it help somehow?

**UPDATE2** `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` gives same results. But when I set `CURLOPT_HEADER` to true, I can see headers (without follow location, with it it still returns false)

**UPDATE3**
I do such things to set cookie:

```
preg_match('/PHPSESSID=([A-Za-z0-9]+)/',$out, $matches);
$cookie="Cookie: PHPSESSID=".$matches[1];
```

And then add to curl:

```
    curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
    curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
```

I've made another connection: `$curl1=curl_init()`
And I do `var_dump` of `$cookie` and headers of responce. The PHPSESSID is different there. I should do, what @baf have said in comments in some other way? 
(you would have to open the form page, store cookies and then post to it again with the cookies)

Comment: Seeing as how this is to do with the different between 3 urls (Google, yours and the desired), its going to be difficult to figure out the error without knowing the url/site involved. Is it a valid domain name? Are you getting connection refused? Sorry if I've misunderstood your question.

Comment: A shot in the dark, but try using the following `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);`

Comment: Maybe you should follow a redirect (`CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`)?

Comment: Well, as far as I don't receive connection refuse, just empty string. It should return something, for example mistake with authentication, or anything like that.

Comment: 2 advices with FOLLOWLOCATION, sure I'll try it

Comment: Please show us what are headers returned by the response. Try ` curl -I http://your-url.com` and edit your post to add returned information (specially the status code). Last time I got an issue like that, it was because the server had some protections against bots and I had to set a user-agent in headers.

Comment: Showed it. Also, to @JohnDevelops domain name is correct. Without http - x.xxx.xxx.com

Comment: to @RaphaëlMalié . Well, I set CURLOPT_USERAGENT. It's not enough?

Comment: It seems you get different result from command line than from php. Try to debug it from php adding `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` and setting `CURLOPT_HEADER` to `true`.

Comment: to @baf results are in update.

Comment: Maybe `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` is disabled on your server. Anyway it seems it is not needed, because there is no redirect. I guess you get empty result because you don't have PHPSESSID or any other value set in the cookie. And server may check for that as a counter bot/spam protection.

Comment: I don't know, is it matter or not, but is this an ajaxForm? What if you try with this on localhost with a test site with a simple form only? Are the field names right?

Comment: to @baf in advanced rest client I can see that there was redirect :
Redirect To:http://desired-site.com/page/page with status: 302 Show explanation HTTP/1.1 302 Found
It is possible that the reason is PHPSESSID. There is no way to circumvent it?

Comment: to @lolka_bolka from sends POST from php without ajax as I can see. But  there is also some PHPSESSID that I suppose is checked on server and ajax. The fields name right.

Comment: If this is really the problem you would have to open the form page, store cookies and then post to it again with the cookies. It is possible in curl, read documentation.

Comment: Thanx all of you, guys for your advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I suggested in the discussion in comments. It stores cookies in a file and makes two requests. One just opens form page and saves the cookies in a cookie jar. Second request posts the data. You may want to give it a try.

```
$jar = tempnam('/tmp', 'cookie'); // create temporary file

$curl = curl_init($url_1); // open form page
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $jar);
curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

$curl = curl_init($url_2); // post data
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $jar);
$out = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

unlink($jar); // delete temporary file
```

Comment: Thats right. Discussion in comments and exactly you helped me a log. So I've approved your answer. But as you can see I do it in one request (exec) and don't use cookiejar/

Comment: @sergey Great that you found a solution. Though I am a bit surprised that setting fake session id (`900000jjsakjas`) works :)

Comment: helped me a lot*, (typo=))
Sure it doesn't work with fake session id, I used it for example.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I've done this. I got `PHPSESSID` from chrome debugger cookie tab. Then I did folowing (just simply send cookie to URL):

```
    if( $curl = curl_init() ) {
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $curlURL);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "PHPSESSID=900000jjsakjas");
    $out = curl_exec($curl);
    echo $out;

    curl_close($curl);
  }
```

This returns fine result.